# Laptop & Netbook's Hard Drives not being detected - both are Toshiba HDDs

Tags: hard-drive, netbook, toshiba-hard-drive

I have a problem with my Acer Aspire One D255, and now again with my Sony Vaio laptop.

The Acer fell about 1 foot 2 days ago. Since then the hard disk is not being detected in the BIOS. I opened the Netbook and removed it and re inserted the hard disk and it worked for like 5 minutes and stopped.

I followed the same thing and again it worked for 2 mins. Now the problem is that even to the slightest movement of laptop the hard disk is not being detected.

I tried swapping the hard disks of the Acer & Sony once to check if it was just a hard disk problem, and now the Sony is now experiencing similar issues with it's hard drive.

After re-inserting them they work for like 2 mins provided they are not moved even the slightest.

The hard disks in both the laptops are Toshiba. Are these hard disks dead? Do you think is there anything with these swapping of disks? Because I have very important data in both of them.

Answer (score 2):

It does sound like the drives have been damaged.  I think it's time to buy some new drives and look into trying to get the data from the old ones while they still work at all.  It might be worth plugging the damaged drives into a desktop PC and transferring the data to that.  Assuming they are sata drives the connectors are the same on desktop and laptop PCs

Comment: yes they are SATA